# Error: type of parameter n (X) does not match that when preparing the plan (Y)

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, plpgsql, prepared-statement

I'm encountering an issue with a PL/pgSQL function where it returns different data types based on a condition, and it's resulting in a type mismatch error. Here's a simplified version of the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(lever int)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    _new_record RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Evaluating the random condition and returning different strings
    IF (lever = 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM
        (VALUES(uuid_generate_anura()))x(id)
        INTO _new_record;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM
        (VALUES(10))x(id)
        INTO _new_record;
    END IF;
    RETURN pg_typeof(_new_record.id)::varchar;
END;
$function$;
```

Note that this is a very simplified version of my complete function. I'm interested in understanding why and how I can work around it.

When calling this function with `lever = 0`, it correctly returns the text `uuid`. However, when calling it with `lever = 1` to force the `ELSE` statement to execute, it throws an error:

```sql
postgres=# select test(0);
 test 
------
 uuid
(1 row)
```

```sql
postgres=# select test(1);
ERROR:  type of parameter 4 (integer) does not match that when preparing the plan (uuid)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test(integer) line 15 at RETURN
```

It doesn't matter the data type, the `ELSE` block will always fail.

Comment: Also note that your function returns different data types *names*, as type `varchar`, not actually different data types, which it couldn't (unless you involve polymorphism, different topic).

Comment: Yes, it is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Also, this inline comment is misleading: `-- Evaluating the random condition and returning different strings`. It's different data types (not strings), which is the problem.

Comment: Technically your session could run `DISCARD plans;` between function calls to work around plpgsql caching. But from a design perspective, your idea is probably to do some kind of polymorphism in tuples, which is often somewhere between hard to impossible in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't matter the data type, the `ELSE` block will always fail.

Actually, the assignment in the `ELSE` block works fine. The error message

> ```
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test(integer) line 15 at RETURN
> ```

refers to:

```
RETURN pg_typeof(_new_record.id)::varchar;
```

A variable of [type (anonymous) `record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) can contain *any row type*, you can even repeatedly assign incompatible row types to the same variable within the same code block.
**But** PL/pgSQL functions (unlike SQL functions) treat all nested SQL statements like prepared statements. Even `record` types have to be the same (or matching) in repeated calls.

So the first call of your function always succeeds. But subsequent calls in the same session have to work with the same prepared statement.

If the problem is only triggered by a particular query plan, we can avoid it using dynamic SQL with [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), where the *plan* is never saved & reused. But tests indicate that the prepared statement itself does not allow the data type to change.

Possible workaround (as hinted by [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe)): a separate assignment for each branch. Each statement looks the same on the surface, but is prepared differently due to the different data type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(lever int, OUT result text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _new_record record;
BEGIN
   -- return different data types  (!) depending on input
   IF lever = 0 THEN
     SELECT random() AS id
     INTO _new_record;
   ELSE
     SELECT 10 AS id
     INTO _new_record;
   END IF;

   -- do stuff

   IF lever = 0 THEN  -- mirror cases at the top!
      result := pg_typeof(_new_record.id);  -- prepared differently!
   ELSE
      result := pg_typeof(_new_record.id);  -- prepared differently!
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aZLnLRNY)

Related:

- [`EXECUTE` statement VS no `EXECUTE` statement in a function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78005024/939860)

For what it's worth, the example you show can be reduced to this simple SQL function (which does not run into the same problem):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(lever int)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
-- Evaluate random condition and return different strings
SELECT CASE lever
          WHEN 0 THEN pg_typeof(uuid_generate_anura())
          ELSE pg_typeof(10)
       END;
$func$;
```

But you already hinted that your case is more involved.

Comment: Would it work to set `plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan` on the function?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I would have expected that it should. But a quick test shows it does not. Which is odd. Re-running my original tests, it turns out I had false positives and my "solution" does not work. Actually, I am not sure, why.

Comment: The parameter data type is part of the prepared statement, I'd say.

Comment: Just I wasn't expecting that the expression in the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` would also qualify for a cached plan. Thinking about it now, that might just be the case. Then again, I don't understand why `SET plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan` wouldn't help, either.

Comment: Because it is still the same statement, even if PostgreSQL generates a new plan each time.

Comment: I think the solution is to have a `RETURN` statement in each branch. They may look the same, but are different.

Comment: I agree, that should do it in any case. Out of time right now, gotta go ...

Comment: As @LaurenzAlbe pointed out, adding a `RETURN` statement in each branch of the if/else fixed the test function. But in my case, this wouldn't be useful. I already find a workaround adding plenty of repetitive code to use different variables along my plpgsql function, so no rush. But I'm really curious about why this happens this.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't really have a clear question. Perhaps you could fix that?

Comment: @RobertoIglesias: I added my variant of a workaround.